# Logic: How to deny this statement?

Tags: logic

Let $f$ be a real function defined on an interval $I$, let $\{f_k\}$ be a sequence of real functions defined also on $I$ and let $c \in I$. I want to deny the following statement:

> For each $\epsilon>0$ and positive integer $K$ there exist $\delta>0$ and a positive integer $m \geq K$ such that $|f_m(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x \in I$ that satisfy $|x-c|<\delta$.

My try: There exists $\epsilon>0$ or a positive integer $K$ such that for all $\delta>0$ or for all a positive integers $m \geq K$, we have $|f_m(x)-f(x)|\geq\epsilon$ for all $x \in I$ that satisfy $|x-c|<\delta$.

I don't know if my try is correct, but I think it's not very easy to understand, I just used the rules of logic to obtain it. I'd appreciate that you could give me a clearer way to deny this statement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The proposition:
$$
\forall \epsilon>0\quad \forall k\in \mathbb N \quad P(\epsilon,k)
$$
reads: *for each $\epsilon>0$ and positive integer $N$...* the negation is
$$
\exists \epsilon>0\quad \exists k \in \mathbb N \quad \neg P(\epsilon,k)
$$
which reads: *there exists $\epsilon>0$ and a positive integer $k$ such that...*.

In particular the *and* in the english phrase remains *and* in the negation.

This example shows how it is important to use formal rules only into a formal language and not in a natural language.

Answer (score 1):

That is not quite correct.  The ‘and’ in “For all $\epsilon > 0$ and positive integer $K$, blah blah” is *not* the  logical and connective that we represent with $\land$.  What it really means is that for every *pair* of numbers $\epsilon$ and $K$ with $\epsilon > 0$ and $K$ a positive integer, etc.  So its negation is “There is a pair of numbers, $\epsilon$ and $K$, etc.

If I were doing this problem, I would start by moving all the quantifiers to the front.  At present there are some quantifiers at the beginning, and some at the end, as an afterthought.  The whole statement has the form that for every blah₁, there is some blah₂ so that (something) for every blah₃.  I would reorder the original statement to have the form for every blah₁, there is some blah₂ so that for every blah₃, (something).  Then negate that.  If you do that, you might notice that the “for every blah₃” turns into “there is some blah₃”, which I see you neglected in your propose solution.

The other thing I'd add is that the original statement is not very clear to understand, so perhaps you shouldn't be concerned if your negation is also not very clear to understand.  The whole thing is highly artificial and there is probably no way to fix that.

---

The other thing you can always do—and I don't recommend this because, although it is perfectly correct and extremely easy, it's probably not what the instructor is looking for—is to write “**It is false that** for each $\epsilon > 0$ and positive integer $K$, …”.  That's the easiest way I know to write the negation of any statement.